# Enable Visio Graphics Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visio-services

On my SharePoint 2010 Farm I have multiple web applications.

How can I enable the Visio Graphics Service Application (Service Application) for just one web application?

[EDIT]
From a licensing point of view, if the Visio Graphics Service is turned on at Farm level is a license required or is it that when the Visio Graphics Service is used in a web application that the licensing requirement is needed?

Answer (score 1):

All services Applications are farm level but you can manage them which Web App want to use it or not.

- When you create a visio graphics Services, it will added into Default **Application Proxy Group**. By default all Web Apps will consume this service.
- Now you have to change the Service Application Associations for Default Group and remove this Services application from here.
- Now again on the same page, create a custom associations for your desired web app and add Visio Services & all others which are required.

How to add/ remove the Services Application associations.

```
Path: Central Admin > Application Management > Configure Service Application Associations
```

[Add or remove service application connections from a web application in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704550(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: I have modified the question to try to gain more information about licensing implications when implementing your suggestion.

Comment: IN 2013 it is little different, any user who access the Visio services should be covered under Enterprise cal. Check this http://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

Comment: If we can restrict who can access the feature via Application Proxy Groups then there seems to be a way to turn on the feature for only a group of people who have permissions to a web application but it is not clear how this impacts licensing.  Do you have the licensing implications for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 the Visio Graphics Service gets enabled at the Farm level as seen in the following image (http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/visio/WindowsLiveWriter/InstallingandConfiguringVisioServices_C8E3/farm%20config%200_thumb.jpg) and not at the Web Application level.

Comment: In this case it still needs the enterprise features to be turned on at site collection level. So if the enterprise features are not turned on at site collection level then is Visio Services still considered to be on?

Comment: You can control it using the service application associations.